# Google App Engine java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the Java7 runtime is not supported anymore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm following the tutorial : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-google-app-engine.html#run_googleapp and upon trying to run the code, I get hit with an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the Java7 runtime is not supported anymore.
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.SharedMain.configureRuntime(SharedMain.java:258)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:374)
at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
```

I have tried adding a runtime tag to my appengine-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>your-app</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```

I am also unable to find my 'App Engine SDK installation' :

```
'C:/Users/acer/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk' is not a valid App Engine SDK installation : 'C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\appcfg.cmd' file not found
```

Thanks in advance for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the error message that you get, I suspect that you are using the App Engine SDK which is now [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sdk-gcloud-migration). The correct plugin that should be used is the [Cloud Code](https://cloud.google.com/code/) one. There is a tutorial on how to do so [here](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/create-standard) Also, you can find more information of how to switch from Java 7 to Java 8 [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8).

Comment: I am using both Java 8 and the Google Cloud SDK. What kind of info would you need?

Comment: also for some reason SO decided to add a java7 tag, so that might've caused the misunderstanding.

Comment: Actually I think that the plugin that you are using needs the App Engine SDK as in the images of the tutorial that you linked, I saw that it expects the App Engine SDK and not the Google Cloud one. I'll check if there is something more up to date and update the answer

Comment: I updated the answer, let me know if it's well explained :)